# Смена позиции элемента массива php

Tags: php

Как из массива а сделать массив b наиболее эффективно?

```
a = array(1,3,4,2,5,6);
b = array(1,3,5,4,2,6);
```

То есть нужно сменить положение одного элемента, но при этом не менять порядок следования других. В примере:  5 становиться в новую позицию после 1 и 3.
Причем нужен такой способ (функция), что б работала и при перестановки элементов как "вперед" так и "назад"!

Например,

```
 array
(
    4 => '4743'
    5 => '4738'
    6 => '4650'
    7 => '4765'
    8 => '4778'
    9 => '4748'
    10 => '4749'
    11 => '4647'
    12 => '4776'
    13 => '4741'
    14 => '4773'

)
 array
(
    4 => '4738'
    5 => '4650'
    6 => '4765'
    7 => '4778'
    8 => '4748'
    9 => '4749'
    10 => '4647'
    11 => '4776'
    12 => '4743'
    13 => '4741'
    14 => '4773'

)
```

элемент 4743(место 4) из первого массива занимает место 12

Comment: иуя не ясно, но очень интересно!

Comment: во первых дайте логику смены элементов, вы только пример дали

Comment: То есть, если мы, в массиве "а", поставим 6 после 4, то должен получиться 1,3,6,4,2,5 ?

Comment: вся проблема со вставкой элемента в массив именно "в то место"  между 4776 и 4741

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для подобных манипуляций есть функция array_splice, она позволят вставлять и извлекать элементы из массива с и по определенным позициям. И возвращает те самые элементы.

```
$a = array(1,3,4,2,5,6);
$from = 4;
$to = 2;

array_splice($a, $to, 0, array_splice($a, $from, 1));

var_dump($a);
```

В данном случае индекс 5 - 4, индекс нужной позиции 2. Извлекаем пятерку и вставляем в нужную позицию.

Comment: что то в этом есть,  спс

Comment: ключи затрутся?

Comment: Да, ключи сбрасываются.